# Can this question be asked? Developing intelligence similar to Batman in the real world

Tags: discussion

In the real world,is it possible for a regular Joe to develop the same intelligence level as the DC fictional character BATMAN?

Answer (score 3):

No, this question would be very much off-topic for skeptics. For further information on what is on-topic see the [helpcenter](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

First off, the question would be out of scope for Skeptics.SE specifically (no notable claim to be examined - NOBODY makes a claim "it is possible for a regular Joe to develop the same intelligence level as the DC fictional character BATMAN", that I'm aware of).

Second of all, even if it was on-topic on some specific SE site (possibly Cognitive Science, or, if you can find an example of someone making this claim notable, here), it'd still be a poor fit and likely to be closed on SE network, because it's too vague to be answerable.

- How do you define "intelligence level" in objective way? IQ? Something else? Your question doesn't specify.
- Nobody knows Batman's intelligence level as a character, including IQ. The comics state he's intelligent but don't quantify it (as far as I know)
- What does "regular Joe" mean? That has no definite meaning.

A question that MAY likely to be answerable (whether it's in scope for CogSci or another SE site, I'm not sure) would be:

> Is it possible for a person to develop from IQ of 100 to IQ of 160?

or

> What are the approaches proven to be effective at raising your IQ level? How much can they raise IQ?